# How to convert a string into byte32 taking account diacritics and uncommon characters using web3

Tags: web3js

When converting a `string` to `byte32`, I assume that part of the content can be lost when truncating:

```js
const data = "PARTIAL COLLECTIÓN / DOCUMENT RECEPTIÓN"
const hex = web3.utils.utf8ToHex(data)
const byte32 = hex.substring(0,64)
console.log(web3.utils.hexToUtf8(hex)) // Right conversion
console.log(web3.utils.hexToUtf8(byte32)) // "Error: Invalid byte index"
```

Is there any method in `web3` that already takes into account the conversion of diacritics and other characters and truncates? I'm ussing Web3 1.10.X.